# Convert a typescript file to a list of commands (history)

Tags: shell, scripting, command-history, typescript

I wanted to record a linux session so I could use it as documentation for a "how to install" guide. I found something on the internet that suggested that the [script command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/script) would be good for this, and so I started it and ran through my installation.

Of course, I didn't read closely enough to realize that the script command actually records *keystrokes*, so when I go to create my documentation it's full of lines that look like this:

```
$ make test[K[K[K[Kinstall[1@s[1@u[1@d[1@o[1@
```

I know that I can use [script replay](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scriptreplay) to play the script back, but what I really want to do is run something like scriptreplay but pipe the list of commands that would get executed to a file (I don't want to actually run them).

Is this possible?

I know about the history command, which I probably should have used instead, but I don't have access to the session's history anymore.

Comment: Maybe I'm too tired, but as I understand the scriptreplay man page, it won't execute the programs anyway: "The replay simply displays the information again; the programs that were run when the typescript was being recorded are not run again."

Comment: Huh, I think you're right! Guess I'm the one that's tired... Unfortunately I don't think I have a paired timing file. Is that something that can be generated?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: check out Mark Lodato's `vt100.py`. It's a lightweight python script that will strip the control characters out of your typescript file, leaving you with only what you would have seen on the terminal.  From there it should be pretty easy to extract the commands you ran.  Find it at https://github.com/MarkLodato/vt100-parser/blob/master/vt100.py

Comment: related: for a simpler case like output that includes status-line updates, `sed 's/.*\r//'` will remove the mess of text and `^M`, leaving only the part of each line after the last carriage return.  (This doesn't work perfectly in the case of  `longer line\rshort`, because sed won't keep the part that `short` didn't overwrite.  But for something like ffmpeg output with status-line updates, it's great.)

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, you could open a shell in emacs with 'M-x shell'. Then the commands you type and the responses are captured in an emacs buffer that you can save to a file.

Answer (score 1):

http://shelr.tv/ is what you need. It allows you to publish  typescripts and replay them locally or on the web. It uses script or ttyrec (when script is broken like on Macs or BSD) internally.

Comment: site is down now :(