# Typescript -terminal recording into video?

Tags: typescript, screencasting

We need to make some videos about working with LaTex documents. We have the typescript and timing -files and now we need to convert them into videos to display them in answers. Basically, the way to do that is to make small Gif -animations. Basically if I could record some area in the X window to GIF, then it would be possible over X to make such videos but it is a bit hxckish way and slow. So how can I convert script -processing into Gif -animations?

```
$ script -t 2> timing   # pastie.org etc to show your working
...WORKING...
$ scriptreplay timing   #how to make them into videos on this site?
```

**Example videos**

The source is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1218429/164148) but created with pay-ware W tool.

[image]

**Perhaps related**

1. [Convert a typescript file to a list of commands (history)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27351/convert-a-typescript-file-to-a-list-of-commands-history)
2. Screencasting in Windows [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/11/screencasting-for-windows.html), what about in *ix?

Comment: `$ apt-cache search screencast
gtk-recordmydesktop - Graphical frontend for recordmydesktop screencast tool
istanbul - Desktop session recorder producing Ogg Theora video
keymon - screencast utility that displays your keyboard and mouse status
screenkey - Screencast your keys` tested screenkey not like that, testing others. If someone finds the recording thing earlier to me, please, answer.

Comment: Maybe this would help https://github.com/nbedos/termtosvg

Answer (score 8):

You can playback your typescript capture and encode the corresponding screen region using something like:

```
ffmpeg -y -f x11grab -s 100x100 -i :0.0+100,100 -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 5 Desktop/capture.gif
```

`-y` overwrites the output (most useful when testing)

`-f x11grab` forces the format to x11grab

`-s 100x100` captured video is 100x100

`-i :0.0+100,100` top left corner is on server 0 screen 0 on pixel 100,100

`-pix_fmt rgb24` forces 24 bpp on input (AFAIK, needed for GIF encoder)

`-r 5` 5 fps

And `Desktop/capture.gif` is my captured file.

Just a note: sometimes the ffmpeg that comes from the distro repositories doesn't have all bells and whistles you may want. If that's the case, you'll need to build it yourself (or find a repo that carries a more complete binary). In my example I used a stock ffmpeg from the Ubuntu repos.

Answer (score 8):

I couldn't get [tty2gif](https://bitbucket.org/antocuni/tty2gif/src/61d5596c9165/tty2gif.py) to work right with vim. So I hacked together [ttygif](https://github.com/icholy/ttygif).

[image: gif]

Comment: This is awesome. I actually found your github while searching for something like this and was debating installing it until I opened up one of my other search tabs and saw you had answered it here. I'm going to install this now.

Comment: Great and simple solution. good job!

Answer (score 6):

Untested: record with [ttyrec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ttyrec), and convert with [tty2gif](https://bitbucket.org/antocuni/tty2gif/src/61d5596c9165/tty2gif.py).

Comment: Works for me. Usage is `./tty2gif typing ttyrecord`. It will record the terminal window you run it in.

Comment: @Inaimathi on which system did you test it? I am trying it on OS X: it loads some ImageMagick things but then fires [errs](http://pastebin.com/NmfDv70w), did you get it like this?

Comment: @hhh - I'm running Debian over here (I think it was Squeeze when I put up that comment). Nope, none of the errors in your paste happened.

Answer (score 3):

most easy way to share typescript is http://shelr.tv/
It uses script or ttyrec as backend and you can puslish your typescript as easy as "shelr push last" :)

Comment: This is extremely cool! Now just some iFrame-video to GIF -conversion so I could easily use that for sharing things in SO. SO does not support iFrames...

Comment: Hey, can you see it?! Look Gilles have the tty2gif part, now just use that to convert the video to Gif and provide people a gif image there -- is that possible? It would make the service a killer...

Comment: I will accept this if it gets the Gif -part, wish I could do a patch to the site :P

Comment: Hey, guys. Web site is open-source so you can easily add postprocessing for uploaded records! https://github.com/shelr/shelr.tv/blob/master/app/controllers/records_controller.rb#L28

Comment: shelr.tv is now official closed down.

Answer (score 1):

A alternative for shelr.tv (which was a great option, and may end up being again) is [showterm](http://showterm.io/) which you can self host, or use as is.

Convert to video as you see fit, this is not a direct to video answer though.

Answer (score 1):

First record terminal session

`ttyrec -e "python run_script.py" rec`

(here any shell command after `-e` that needs to be executed and recorded from start to end)

Then convert it to gif

`ttygif rec`

After that file `tty.gif` appears in current dir, you can view it through

`xdg-open tty.gif`

Tools above should be installed by:

`sudo apt install ttyrec ttygif`

Tested to work on Ubuntu with `xterm` terminal program.

Also, if you want to convert GIF above to MP4 video do:

```
ffmpeg -i tty.gif -movflags faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" -crf 15 tty.mp4
```

(which needs installing ffmpeg through `sudo apt install ffmpeg`)